# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 123: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

I wrote this code:

```
@app.route('/cafes')
def cafes():
    with open('cafe-data.csv', newline='') as csv_file
        csv_data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        list_of_rows = []
        for row in csv_data:
            list_of_rows.append(row)
   return render_template('cafes.html', cafes=list_of_rows)
```

But got this error on my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding on the csvfile, default is `'utf-8'` but there are others like `'cp-1252'` that are commonly used as well.

```
with open('cafe-data.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    ...
```